# How to write Rootkit in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

My teacher tells me rootkit is the easiest program ever.
Is my teacher correct?
I already tried to write the hello world

```
Write-Host 'Hello World!'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not real sure why you posted this to a PowerShell forum, that is not what we are here for. but...

As for...

> the easiest program ever

In general, these types of blanket statement are just foolishness.

Easy is a matter of knowledge, skill, technique, understanding, application, experience and opinion. If you are lacking / limited in the aforementioned, then easy is not something that can be used as a mantra.

The normal espoused easiest program to write is 'Hello world' apps. It's taught in all programming courses/classes and all languages.

So, yes, your teacher is wrong, in the use of such a blanket statement and probably time for you to look for another educator.

Research this for yourself. Read a few papers on designing malware/rootkits for different platforms, and see if such a blanket statement is valid.

Just use your search engine of choice to find such papers.